# How to get $el in petite vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, petite-vue

From the example inside the [petite vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue) repo:

```html
<script type="module">
  import { createApp } from 'https://unpkg.com/petite-vue?module'

  createApp({
    // exposed to all expressions
    count: 0,
    // getters
    get plusOne() {
      return this.count + 1
    },
    // methods
    increment() {
      this.count++
    }
  }).mount()
</script>

<div v-scope>
  <p>{{ count }}</p>
  <p>{{ plusOne }}</p>
  <button @click="increment">increment</button>
</div>
```

When I am trying to get a `p` tag like so:

```html
<p ref="foobar">{{ count }}</p>
```

This returns an error, since `this.$refs.foobar` is `undefined`:

```js
increment() {
  console.log(this.$refs.foobar.$el)
  this.count++
}
```

How can I get the HTML element inside my javascript through `$el`?

Comment: Have you tried logging just `$el`? For example: `console.log($el);` I believe _petitie-vue_ is different than the standard library in that `$el` points to the current element the directive is bound too ***not*** the component root element.

Comment: Looking [at those](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue/discussions?discussions_q=ref), it looks like it's totally feasible. Meanwhile, I'm not sure of the exact syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to @kissu for pointing me to the right discussion form, where I found the answer.

So apparently `$refs` only works inside of the "component" concept within petite vue.

If you have the following snippet, from the docs, with a `ref` added to the `p` tag:

```html
<script type="module">
  import { createApp } from 'https://unpkg.com/petite-vue?module'

  function Counter(props) {
    return {
      count: props.initialCount,
      inc() {
        this.count++
      },
      mounted() {
        console.log(`I'm mounted!`)
      }
    }
  }

  createApp({
    Counter
  }).mount()
</script>

<div v-scope="Counter({ initialCount: 1 })" @vue:mounted="mounted">
  <p ref="foobar">{{ count }}</p>
  <button @click="inc">increment</button>
</div>
```

You'll be able to do:

`this.$refs.foobar` from within that function, to get the element. Note: `$el` is not needed.